why onWindowFocusChanged not called
I try to share clipboard content ower network using with zxing QRCode and camera. I readed that onWindowFocuseChanged event is capable to access clipboard content and it works most of time. The clipDataOnResume member sometimes is null in onActivityResult. ("clipDataOnResume is null at onActivityResult" toast message appears).
What can I do to avoid this? I use thes components:
implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0")
implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0")

ActivityMain content:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var clipDataOnResume: ClipData? = null
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        binding.btnScan.setOnClickListener {
            val scanner = IntentIntegrator(this)
            scanner.setOrientationLocked(true)
            scanner.setPrompt("Scan a barcode.")
            scanner.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
            scanner.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true)
            scanner.initiateScan()
        }
    }

    fun sendContentTask(url: String, clipboardContent: String): Int {
// Send clipboard content over network
    }

    fun getContentTask(url: String): String {
// Get clipboard content over network
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled from fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else {
                if (result.getContents().endsWith("post")) {
                    val manager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                    var clipContent = ""
                    if (manager.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                        val clipData = manager.primaryClip
                        val item = clipData!!.getItemAt(0)
                        clipContent = item.text.toString()
                    } else if (clipDataOnResume != null && clipDataOnResume!!.itemCount > 0) {
                        val item = clipDataOnResume!!.getItemAt(0)
                        clipContent = item.text.toString()
                    }

                    if (clipContent == ""){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "clipDataOnResume is null at onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        val url = result.getContents();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Location: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        runBlocking {
                            var result: Deferred<Unit> = async() {
                                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                    val msg = sendContentTask(url, clipContent)
                                }
                            }
                            result.await()
                        }
                    }
                } else if (result.getContents().endsWith("get")) {
                    val url = result.getContents()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Location: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    runBlocking {
                        var msg = ""
                        var result: Deferred<Unit> = async() {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                msg = getContentTask(url)
                            }
                        }
                        result.await()
                        setClipboardContent(msg)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
            val manager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
            clipDataOnResume = manager.primaryClip
            if (clipDataOnResume == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "clipDataOnResume is null at focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

}


Other views within your activity layout eg Button or EditText have focus by default, onWindowFocusChanged will not be triggered in that case consider using function requestWindowFocus().

Ok, I reorganized my code. I put the process of QR code to onWindowFocusChanged (processQRresult).
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var clipDataOnResume: ClipData? = null
    var QRresult: IntentResult? = null
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        binding.btnScan.setOnClickListener {
            val scanner = IntentIntegrator(this)
            scanner.setOrientationLocked(true)
            scanner.setPrompt("Scan a barcode.")
            scanner.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
            scanner.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true)
            scanner.initiateScan()
        }
    }

    fun setClipboardContent(result: String) {
        val clipboard = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(null, result))
    }

    fun sendContentTask(url: String, clipboardContent: String): Int {
        var result: Int
        try {
            val client: CloseableHttpClient =
                HttpClients.createDefault()
            val httpPost = HttpPost(url)

            val params: MutableList<NameValuePair> = ArrayList()
            params.add(BasicNameValuePair("content", clipboardContent))
            if (url.endsWith("jsonpost")) {
                val json = JSONObject()
                json.put("content", clipboardContent)
                val requestEntity =
                    StringEntity(
                        json.toString(),
                        ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON
                    )
                httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity)
            } else if (url.endsWith("post")) {
                httpPost.setEntity(
                    org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        params,
                        "UTF-8"
                    )
                )
            }
            val response: CloseableHttpResponse =
                client.execute(httpPost)
            result = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
            client.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.message.toString())
            result = 500
        } finally {
        }
        return result
    }

    fun getContentTask(url: String): String {
        var result = ""
        try {
            val client = HttpClients.createDefault()
            val httpGost = HttpGet(url)

            val response = client.execute(httpGost)

            val entity = response.entity
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8")

            client.close()
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.message.toString())
            result = ""
        } finally {
        }
        return result
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        QRresult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
            val manager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
            clipDataOnResume = manager.primaryClip
            if (clipDataOnResume == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "clipDataOnResume is null at focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                processQRresult()
            }
        }
    }

    fun processQRresult() {
        if (QRresult != null) {
            if (QRresult!!.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled from fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                if (QRresult!!.getContents().endsWith("post")) {
                    val manager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                    var clipContent = ""
                    if (manager.hasPrimaryClip()) {
                        val clipData = manager.primaryClip
                        val item = clipData!!.getItemAt(0)
                        clipContent = item.text.toString()
                    } else if (clipDataOnResume != null && clipDataOnResume!!.itemCount > 0) {
                        val item = clipDataOnResume!!.getItemAt(0)
                        clipContent = item.text.toString()
                    }

                    if (clipContent == ""){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "clipDataOnResume is null at onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        val url = QRresult!!.getContents();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Location: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        runBlocking {
                            var result: Deferred<Unit> = async() {
                                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                    val msg = sendContentTask(url, clipContent)
                                }
                            }
                            result.await()
                        }
                    }
                } else if (QRresult!!.getContents().endsWith("get")) {
                    val url = QRresult!!.getContents()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Location: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    runBlocking {
                        var msg = ""
                        var result: Deferred<Unit> = async() {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                msg = getContentTask(url)
                            }
                        }
                        result.await()
                        setClipboardContent(msg)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



